# Data type Mismatch in criteria expression in MS Accss2010

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I tried execute INSERT query, but it throwing above error. I have given my code below.

```
public string InsertMoveDetails(string desc, string currentLocation, string newLocation, string newBay, string requestedBy, string movedBy, string approvedBy, DateTime dateOfMove)
{

        string desc, currentLocation, newLocation, movedBy, approvedBy, requestedBy,newBay;
        DateTime dateOfMove;

        desc = textBoxDescription.Text;
        currentLocation = textBoxCurrentLocation.Text;
        newLocation = comboBoxNewLocation.Text;
        movedBy = comboBoxMovedBy.Text;
        approvedBy = comboBoxApprovedBy.Text;
        dateOfMove = dateTimePickerDateOfMove.Value;           
        newBay = textBoxNewBay.Text;
        requestedBy = textBoxRequestedBy.Text;

        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO MoveDetails(Descrptn, CurrentLocation, NewLocation, NewBay, RequestedBy, MovedBy, ApprovedBy, DateOfMove) VALUES(@Descrptn, @CurrentLocation, @NewLocation, @NewBay, @RequestedBy, @MovedBy, @ApprovedBy, @DateOfMove)", con);

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrptn", desc);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentLocation", currentLocation);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewLocation", newLocation);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewBay", newBay);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedBy", requestedBy);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovedBy", movedBy);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApprovedBy", approvedBy);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfMove", dateOfMove);

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return "";
    }
```

My database columns and their respective types are

Descrptn- Text
CurrentLocation- Text
NewLocation- Text
NewBay- Text
RequestedBy- Text
MovedBy- Text
ApprovedBy- Text
DateOfMove- Date/Time

Please help me with this error. I tried the other threads with same error, but i can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this code.

```
dateOfMove = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerDateOfMove.Text);
```

That's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try with removing @ from all parameter and in SQL replace all parameters with ?, i dont think Access supports named parameters.

Comment: It's working with other forms. (I have multiple forms). I think @ parameter  not a problem.

Comment: I already tried that resource. No resolution..anyway thanks for your effort.